# "Configure Block" region highlight missing in Drupal 7

Tags: blocks, theming

The usual region highlight (a dashed-line border around the region) with a little gear icon that opens up a drop down saying "Configure Block" is missing on my custom Drupal 7 site. Which or What admin option is responsible for this?

- I am logged in an an administrator.
- I have actual regions.
- Those regions have data.
- "Demonstrate Block Regions" shows where the regions are correctly.

How do I bring this highlighting back?

Contextual Links module is enabled.

This is my block.tpl-

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<div class="block-inner clearfix">
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>

<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

<div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php print $content; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have the Contextual Links module enabled.
2. If you're overriding the [default block template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) in your theme, make sure you're printing the `$title_prefix` and `$title_suffix` vars; I forget which one, but one of those contains the markup for the contextual links javascript.

Comment: I think I've printed those vars. Updated original question.

Comment: Easy test - switch the default theme to Bartik temporarily. If the links aren't there, you don't have Contextual Links enabled. If they _are_ there, something in your theme is broken

Comment: Contextual Links are enabled. I guess it must be something in the theme then?

Comment: At a guess, yeah...but you can tell for certain if you enable Bartik temporarily

Comment: I did enable Bartik and my usual regions did not show up. I've also checked the Modules page at the Admin area. It's confirmed either way.

Comment: Ah, it should work in the admin area if you're using the 7 theme (unless it's altered of course). Do you have any JS errors in the console?

Comment: I've removed all JS from my site temporarily. No errors or warnings appear. It's still the same.